# Accept only N numbers of same Id in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

**Table 1**

```
IDProduct | Price
--------- | -----
1         | $500
2         | $100
```

**Table 2**

```
IDProduct | Desc
--------- | ------
1         | Desc 1
1         | Desc 2
1         | Desc 3
```

What I want to do is only accept a total of 3 register with the same Id in Table 2, like the above example, if I try to register another row with Id 1 an error must happen or something, is this possible to do in Sql Server or I need to handle this outside sql (js, php, c#, etc.)

In other simple words I want that my Table 1 only accepts a total of 3 rows with the same IdProduct, maybe I have to try it with a trigger? an stored procedure with if, else?

Comment: Use a trigger, according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398747/can-you-limit-the-number-of-rows-in-a-database-table).

Comment: It can be done [without triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23510713/15498), but I'd still not recommend that technique.

Comment: I would also say this should be done in business layer of the application.

Comment: Trigger will be the best choice..

Comment: You can add a CHECK CONSTRAINT on the table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Stored procedure, you can simply achieve this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_InsertProduct]
(   @ProductId   INT, @Price DECIMAL (9,2)   ) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ProductCount AS INT = 0
    SELECT @ProductCount = COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE IDProduct = @ProductId   

   IF @ProductCount < 3
       INSERT INTO Table1 (IDProduct, Price) VALUES (@ProductId, @Price)
   ELSE
      -- You can RAISEERROR or some other way to notify the insert is not happen

END
```

Comment: This *may* work but you'd want to put better protection around it (explicit transaction, exclusive lock during select) if there's any possibility that you're building a system that has to support more than a single user at a time. Otherwise there's an obvious race here where two sessions perform a count, both observe the count is less than 3, then both insert and take the count over 3.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` with a `User Defined Function` can solve this.

First create UDF `dbo.CheckIDProduct` to get the count of a `IDProduct` from `Table_2`

After that add a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on `Table_2`

```
ALTER TABLE Table_2
  ADD CONSTRAINT chkIDProductCount
  CHECK (dbo.CheckIDProduct(IDProduct) <= 2);
```